# Implementation of Hashtag many-to-many relationship using parse?

Tags: iphone, ios, many-to-many, database-schema, parse-platform

I recently discovered the power of using backend as a service platform in my applications they are great but the problem is there are not many tutorials to guide you through so many peculiar database structure implementation on these platforms, so I came up with this popular scenario to get some clarity

The structure is user can write a post and attach hashtags (up to 'n') to it , these hashtags could obviously be attached to many posts,this is typical many-to-many relationship scenario how would you propose the database structure for the implementation of following queries?

1. the user table has a location column, the query is to get all the posts for a particular hashtag within 50 miles of current user location?
2. popular hashtags(attached to the post created by other users) around current user location

P.S. these were some general scenarios I could think of, append any other popular scenario in your answers if you think would be helpful to the Parse community.

Answer (score 1):

Parse doesn't provide a full relational database, but you can add a relational column to a data class, which allows many-to-many associations between classes. So you could, for example, have a `hashtag` class, and add a relation column to your `post` class containing its associated hashtags. Query 1 could be answered by building a query against the `hashtag` class , specifying the desired hashtags, then adding that as a subquery of a query against the `post` class. In your containing query you'd specify that you were looking for `post`s near the user's location. E.g.

```
PFQuery *tagQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"hashtag"];
[tagQuery whereKey:@"tagName" equalTo:@"hash_tag_name"];

PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"post"];
[postQuery whereKey:@"hashtags" matchesQuery:tagQuery];
[postQuery whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userLocation withinMiles:50.0];

[postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    //Do something with results
}];
```

I can't think of a straightforward way of pulling the data for your second query out with a single Parse query. One approach would be to just retrieve the `post`s near the current location, and then iterate through them to determine the tags associated with each one (and count their frequency).

Another option altogether would be to just store tags as an array of strings against a post. You could then query by tag using `whereKey:equalTo:` (single tag) or `whereKey:containedIn:` (multiple tags). With this approach, you'd need to keep track of which tags existed elsewhere.